# Using Angular CLI with the latest AspNetCore Angular 4 Spa template

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application, angular-cli

I am attempting to use Angular CLI with the latest JavaScriptServices AspNetCore Angular Spa template.

I used to simply just copy and pase a .angular-cli.json file in the root directory of my project and change "root": to "ClientApp" and would be good to go.

However, now with this new version of the template when I run 'ng g component mycomponent' it fails because it can't find app.module.ts. The reason for this is because in this new template they split app.module.ts into 3:

app.module.client.ts, app.module.server.ts, app.module.shared.ts

Any ideas on how to still make this work?

Comment: There are options you can use to tell ng what module to use, or to skip the module import all together. You can find the information in the ng cli wiki [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component).

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, but I'm planning to use the Targetting module without affecting much the underlying code. Off topic, did you manage to run the NG Serve?

Answer (score 2):

[SOLUTION]

1. Rename app.module.client.ts to app.client.module.ts
2. Open app.client.module.ts: prepend the declaration with 3 dots “...” and wrap the declaration in brackets.

   *For example: `[...sharedConfig.declarations, <MyComponent>]`*
3. Open  boot-client.ts: update your import to use the new
   app.client.module reference.

   *For example: `import { AppModule } from './app/app.client.module';`*
4. Now try to generate the new component: `ng g component my-component`

[EXPLANATION]

Angular CLI looks for a file named app.module.ts in your project, and tries to find a references for the declarations property to import the component. This should be an array (as the sharedConfig.declarations is), but the changes do not get applied

[SOURCES]

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2962
- https://www.udemy.com/aspnet-core-angular/learn/v4/t/lecture/6848548 (section 3.33 lecture contributor Bryan Garzon)

Comment: @Abiezer what are you experiencing? Any specific errors or load issues? If you can send any full page screenshots, I'm happy to help. Also maybe include the versions of your packages

Comment: i cant post everything but basically the angular cli does not modify the app.client.module.ts it says :

"No app module found. Please add your new class to your component.
Identical ClientApp\app\app.client.module.ts

Comment: @Abiezer no problem. There are a few things you could try: from step #3 above, make sure that the path to app.client.module is correct...specifically, in your import statement (the "from" section) in boot-client.ts, make sure you are correctly pointing to the location of this file with "./" or "../", depending on your setup. App.client.module should be in the root of your app folder. Also, when runing the "ng g component" from the command line, make sure you are in the root project directory...or at the very least, specify the directory you intend to generate the component in.

Comment: @Abiezer when all else fails, I always do what I like to call the Marty McFly: restart Visual Studio, Clean and Rebuild the solution, and restore all your packages (right click packages.json and select Restore Packages). Not necessarily in that order....Oh, and of course, make sure the flux capacitor is running at least 1.21 gigawatts

Comment: @Abiezer one last idea: take a look at any files you have excluded from the project. They may be hidden in VS, but still existing in the folder. It may be possible you have the same-named file "app.client.module", with different capitalization

Comment: This is not working for me using VS2017 V15.3. I have app.module.browser, app.module.server and app.module.shared. Which one do I change? Also I'm not quite sure what is meant by the prepend with 3 dots step. I just get errors when I try that. Could you let me know which file out of my three I should change and could you paste in the code for the prepend step. That would be very helpful.